# Regular expression in php with preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex

I would like to create a way of matching strings like

```
abc(xyz)
abc
abc(xyz)[123]
```

where each bracket is an optional unit. What I would like to have, optimally, is something like

```
preg_match_all('complicated regex', $mystring, $matches);
```

with `$matches` returning the following:

- If `$mystring= abc(xyz)[123]R` gives `$matches=array(0 => "abc", 1=> "xyz", 2=> "123", 3=> "R")`
- If `$mystring= abc(xyz)R` gives `$matches=array(0 => "abc", 1=> "xyz", 2=> "", 3=> "R")`
- If `$mystring= abc[123]R` gives `$matches=array(0 => "abc", 1=> "", 2=> "123", 3=> "R")`
- If `$mystring= abc(xyz)[123]` gives `$matches=array(0 => "abc", 1=> "xyz", 2=> "123", 3=> "")`
- If `$mystring= abc` gives `$matches=array(0 => "abc", 1=> "", 2=> "", 3=> "")`

I hope you get the point. I tried as follows:

```
preg_match_all("/([a-z]*)(\([a-zA-Z]\))?(\[\w\])?/", "foo(dd)[sdfgh]", $matches)
```

for which `matches[0]` is

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => 
    [2] => dd
    [3] => 
    [4] => 
    [5] => sdfgh
    [6] => 
    [7] => 
)
```

why do I get the additional empty matches? How to avoid them to have results as I need to (either in `matches` or in `matches[0]`...).

Comment: The `R` at the end makes it irregular, because it's not possible to match `R` only if either `(123)` or `[123]` or both have been matched; for example, what about `abcR`?

Answer (score 1):

You get so many results because your match starts on and on again 8 times. All The string (including empty strings) are matched against the first, non-optinal part of the regex: `([a-z]*)`.

The corrected regex:

```
preg_match_all("/^([a-z]*)(\([a-zA-Z]*\))?(\[\w*\])?$/", "foo(ddd)[sdfgh]", $matches);
```

**EDIT** (to exclude brackets in the second part of the subject)
So we want `'ddd'` instead of `'(ddd)'`:

This regex uses a "non capturing pattern" `(?: ... )` in order to mark an optional part of the subject, but not to capture it in the matches array.

```
preg_match_all("/^([a-z]*)(?:\(([a-zA-Z]*)\))?(\[\w*\])?$/", "foo(ddd)[sdfgh]", $matches);
```

The interesting part is this: `(?:\(([a-zA-Z]*)\))?`.

- first paren `(?:` marks the beginning of a non capturing subpattern
- second paren `\(` is an escaped literal paren
- third one `(` mark the beginning of standard capturing subpattern

Only contents of the third parens pair will show up in the $matches array.

Comment: Best answer so far, but is there a way to recover the bracket matches as `ddd` instead `(ddd)`?

Answer (score 1):

how about:

```
/^(\w*)(?:\((\w*)\))?(?:\[(\w*)\])(\w*)?$/
```

usage:

```
preg_match_all("/^(\w*)(?:\((\w*)\))?(?:\[(\w*)\])(\w*)?$/", "abc[123]R", $matches); 
print_r($matches);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => abc[123]R
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => abc
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => R
        )

)
```

**explanation:**

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:^(\w*)(?:\((\w*)\))?(?:\[(\w*)\])(\w*)?$)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w*                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (0 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \(                       '('
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      \w*                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (0
                               or more times (matching the most
                               amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \)                       ')'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \[                       '['
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \3:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      \w*                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (0
                               or more times (matching the most
                               amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \3
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \]                       ']'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \4 (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w*                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (0 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of \4 (NOTE: because you are using a
                           quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
                           repetition of the captured pattern will be
                           stored in \4)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

And why don't you use [preg_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) ?

```
$string = 'abc(xyz)[123]';
$array = preg_split('/\]?\(|\)\[?|\[|\]/', $string);
print_r($array);
```

[Online Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/DSly6a)

Comment: @Alex Sorry, forgot the delimiters :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this simple regex:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

When using `preg_match_all` it will find all substrings which match the given pattern and separate them in groups if there are braces, brackets or other characters between them.

```
preg_match_all("/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "foo(dd)[sdfgh]", $matches);
print_r($matches);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => foo
            [1] => dd
            [2] => sdfgh
        )

)
```

If for some reason you need to have the braces and brackets separately you could use grouping like this:

```
([\(\)\[\]])?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)([\(\)\[\]])?

preg_match_all("/([\(\)\[\]])?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)([\(\)\[\]])?/", "foo(dd)[sdfgh]", $matches); 
print_r($matches);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => foo(
            [1] => dd)
            [2] => [sdfgh]
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
            [2] => [
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => foo
            [1] => dd
            [2] => sdfgh
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => (
            [1] => )
            [2] => ]
        )

)
```

Comment: This does not exactly solve my problem, as for a string like `foo[sdfgh]` I get TWO matches, whereas I need three: `foo`, empty string as there is no normal bracket, and `sdfgh`.

Answer (score 0):

A way to obtain what you need without empty items:

```
$pattern = '~(?|\[(\w*+)]|\(([a-zA-Z]*+)\)|\b([a-z]*+)\b)~';
preg_match_all($pattern, 'foo(dd)[sdfgh]', $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Notice : this can match empty strings in brackets, to avoid them, replace * by +

Answer (score 0):

The optional last letter throws off the results a bit, but this expression will cover it:

```
function doit($s)
{
        echo "==== $s ====\n";
        preg_match_all('/(\w+) # first word
                (?: \(([^)]+)\) )? # match optional (xyz)
                (?: \[([^]]+)\])? # match optional [123]
                (\w?) # match optional last char
                /x', $s, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

        print_r($matches);
}

doit('abc(xyz)[123]R xyz(123)');
doit('abc(xyz)R');
doit('abc[123]R');
doit('abc(xyz)[123]');
```

**Results**

```
==== abc(xyz)[123]R xyz(123) ====
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => abc(xyz)[123]R
            [1] => abc
            [2] => xyz
            [3] => 123
            [4] => R
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => xyz(123)
            [1] => xyz
            [2] => 123
            [3] => 
            [4] => 
        )

)
==== abc(xyz)R ====
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => abc(xyz)R
            [1] => abc
            [2] => xyz
            [3] => 
            [4] => R
        )

)
==== abc[123]R ====
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => abc[123]R
            [1] => abc
            [2] => 
            [3] => 123
            [4] => R
        )

)
==== abc(xyz)[123] ====
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => abc(xyz)[123]
            [1] => abc
            [2] => xyz
            [3] => 123
            [4] => 
        )

)
```